# Classical Java synchronization problem (care to give it a try?)

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, distributed, parallel-processing

I'm trying to solve a Java synchronization problem. The case is as follows:

There are class Persons and they want to be paired. So I have a class Coupling that does the pairing. When a person walks in to the Coupling and there is no one waiting for her, she starts to wait. And waits until someone comes along or she gets bored and leaves (predifines timer goes off).

If she walks in and finds someone waiting for her, they are immediately coupled and they exchange phone numbers and go their separate ways. (Continue execution with the other's information.)

The same person can't leave with two people.

I promise that this is not a university exercise I'm trying to cheat in. :) I just havn't done this stuff in a while and I'm a bit rusty at it.

This is something I came with up at first, so the Thread is trying to set the Person, and if this doesn't work it'll get false as return value. Then the thread gets the waiter. For obvious reasons, this will not work (another thread might come between the calls) and how would I signal the waiting thread to go on.

Here's the code I mentioned:

```
public class Coupling {
    private static volatile Person waitingPerson = null;

    public static synchronized Integer getWaitingPerson() {
        Integer temp = waitingPerson;
        waitingPerson = null;
        return temp;
    }

    public static synchronized Boolean setWaitingPerson(Integer waitingPerson) {
        if (waitingPerson == null){
            syncro.waitingPerson = waitingPerson;
            return new Boolean(true);
        }
        else
            return new Boolean(false);
}
```

Comment: in this exercise, where do the threads come into play? how many threads do you have, what do they represent, etc?

Comment: why are you using both `volatile` AND `synchronized`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution

```
private final Exchanger<Person> waitingPerson = new Exchanger<Person>();

public Person getWaitingPerson(Person person, int timeoutMS) 
        throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
    return waitingPerson.exchange(person, timeoutMS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

---

I assume that these Persons have no sexual preference. ;)

I assume a `Person` cannot turn into an `Integer`

You talked about waiting but you don't wait anywhere. ;)

This would be much simpler to implement using BlockingQueues.

BTW: Never use `new Boolean(true)` or `new Boolean(false)` in fact there is no reason not to use `boolean`

Comment: These are comments.  Not really an answer.

Comment: In this case, there's no reason to use `boolean`. But sometimes you'll need to use `AtomicBoolean`.

Comment: @noob, As a return value for a constant?

Comment: @Gray, I was hoping that the OP would give code which compiled or answers to the questions, but instead I will just give my answer. ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: No, I thought you were saying for multi-threading in general, which is not what my experiences have taught me. :)

Comment: @Peter: It looks like your timeout does not really works like it should when looking at the method from the outside, as you repeat your waiting then if no person is yet found. (For the second solution.)

Comment: I don't think this works Peter.  Looks to me like coupledPerson will always be null to other threads.  Remember that notifyAll does not relinquish the lock so the coupledPerson will always be set back to null in the finally before the other thread can see it.  I think the setting of null should be done by the consumer.

Comment: I agree, it not a simple problem, and difficult to prove correctness. I would just use an Exchanger as its a one liner. Removing my other solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can this work however, I mean the thread is waiting in a synchronized method. Doesn't it just block all the other threads from coming in but refuse to leave the method before being coupled? (or timer runs out)?

Comment: the Integer temp was my bad, was suppose to be Person temp. Sorry.

Comment: When you wait() it gives up the lcok allowing other threads to get it.  The Exchanger doesn't use synchronized making it more efficient. It also happens to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I just now realized the power of the Exchanger! That'll work and it's actually quite an elegant solution (I know, Dijkstra rolls over in his grave for that). Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

If you really just want to get into this stuff and this is your example problem, try to get a copy of [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/), and find out for yourself. Its a great book.

Comment: Sounds like an advertisement.

Comment: @noob: Hehe, yes, you are right. But accidentially I really love this book. I swear I do not profit from this book :).

Answer (score 1):

**How not to do it.** Rough solution I put together after tackling something similar for a test recently. Has issues as noted in a comment below.

```
public class Coupling implements Runnable {

    private static Person waitingPerson = null;

    private static Person secondPerson = null;

    private static final Object waitLock = new Object();

    // Time out after a second
    private static final Integer TIMEOUT = 1000;

    public static Person getWaitingPerson(Person incoming) {

        Person match = null;

        // We're the second person in.
        synchronized (waitLock) {
            if (waitingPerson != null) {

                // Get the person who is waiting
                match = waitingPerson;
                waitingPerson = null;
                secondPerson = incoming;

                // Let the other person know
                waitLock.notify();
                return match;
            }
        }

        // We're the first person in, wait for a second
        synchronized(waitLock){
            waitingPerson = incoming;
            try {
                // Wait until someone is available
                waitLock.wait(TIMEOUT);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(secondPerson != null){
                // Get the other person
                match = secondPerson;
                secondPerson = null;
                return match;
            } else {
                // We timed out, reset
                waitingPerson = null;
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I've intentionally ignored any specifics of the Person class (not sure what your Integer temp was supposed to do).

Comment: There are some serious race conditions with this model.  If enough threads queue up on the waitLock, then multiple threads could get the same secondPerson.  It's important to realize that just because something has been notified does not mean it runs next.  It just means it goes back into the ready queue *behind* whatever threads are already there.

Comment: Very good point, thanks for the critique. Explains some weird behaviours I was seeing with my test app the other day. I'll leave it up as a warning to others.

Comment: Here's a good page I wrote a while page on race conditions in response to what I think is a wrong stackoverflow answer.  http://256.com/gray/docs/misc/producer_consumer_race_conditions/

Comment: the Integer temp was my bad, was suppose to be Person temp. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'll mangle your problem a little bit and propose a solution, then you'll tell me if you're satisfied :-)

First, have you considered making the "pairing" operation asynchronous? It would work pretty much like this:

1. A Person who wants to be paired, leaves a notification at a Coupling thread;
2. When a second person leaves a "free" notification, the Coupling thread notifies the two people.

How would that work in code? Well, you'd need two things:

1. A lock that supports accumulated permits (a semaphore!);
2. A thread safe data structure (well, just in case. It really doesn'd *need* to be thread safe)

So, every time a Person wants to be paired, it notifies the Coupling thread, that adds the Person to its "free people" list and releases one permit from the semaphore. The Coupling thread, on the other hand continuously try to acquire semaphore permits, two at a time. Since a permit is only released when a Person leaves a notification, having two permits means that two people want to be paired.

Well, less talk, more code. Here's the Coupling thread class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Coupling implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue<Person> peopleQueue;

    private Semaphore semaphore;

    public Coupling() {
        this.peopleQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Person>();
        this.semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            // Process incoming "free" events

            try {
                // Acquire permits for two people
                this.semaphore.acquire(2);

                Person pA = this.peopleQueue.poll();
                Person pB = this.peopleQueue.poll();

                pA.notifyPairing(pB);
                pB.notifyPairing(pA);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  // This shouldn't really happen..?
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Invoked to notify that a Person is waiting for a coupling
     * @param person
     */
    public void notifyFreePerson(Person person) {
        this.peopleQueue.offer(person);
        this.semaphore.release(1);
    }
}
```

And the Person class:

```
public class Person {
    public void notifyPairing(Person other) {
        System.out.printf("I've been paired with %s!\n)", other);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like it. I was thinking Semaphore as well, since we need a count of some sort. I might have naively made the notifyFreePerson method synchronized, but I think it works well the way you have it.